# How do you dynamically load a CSS file into a Flex application?

Tags: css, apache-flex, dynamic-css

I know that you can apply CSS in order to style objects in Flex using the StyleManager:
http://livedocs.adobe.com/flex/3/html/help.html?content=styles_07.html

You can also load **compiled** CSS files (SWFs) dynamically:
http://livedocs.adobe.com/flex/3/html/help.html?content=styles_10.html

However, I'm dynamically creating my CSS files using a web GUI and a server-side script.
If the CSS is changed, then the script would also need to compile the CSS into an SWF (which is not a viable option).  Is there any way around this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The application of CSS in Flex is handled on the server side at compilation and not on the client side at run time.

I would see two options then for you (I'm not sure how practical either are):

1. Use a server side script to compile your CSS as a SWF then load them dynamically.
2. Parse a CSS Style sheet and use the setStyle functions in flex to apply the styles. An similar example to this approach is the [Flex Style Explorer](http://examples.adobe.com/flex3/consulting/styleexplorer/Flex3StyleExplorer.html) where you can check out the [source](http://examples.adobe.com/flex3/consulting/styleexplorer/srcview/index.html).

Good luck.

Answer (score 3):

In [this comment](http://bugs.adobe.com/jira/browse/SDK-11868#action_186925) to an issue related to this in the Adobe bug tracker *T. Busser* is describing what might be a viable solution for you:

> *"I've created a small class that will 'parse' a CSS file read with an
>   HTTPService object. It takes apart the
>   string that is returned by the
>   HTTPService object, break it down into
>   selectors, and create a new
>   CSSStyleDeclaration object for each
>   selector that is found. Once all the
>   properties are assigned to the
>   CSSStyleDeclaration object it's added
>   to the StyleManager. It doesn't
>   perform any checks, you should make
>   sure the CSS file is well formed, but
>   it will be sufficient 99% of the time.
>   Stuff like @font, Embed() and
>   ClassReference() will hardly be used
>   by my customers. They do need the
>   ability to change colors and stuff
>   like that so they can easily theme the
>   Flex application to their house
>   style."*

You could either try to contact this person for their solution or alternatively maybe use the code from [this as3csslib project](http://code.google.com/p/as3csslib/) as a basis for writing something like what they're describing.

Answer (score 2):

*Edit: This solution does not work. All selectors that are taken out of the parser are converted to lowercase. This may work for your application but it will probably not...*

*I am leaving this answer here because it may help some people looking for a solution and warn others of the limitations of this method.*

---

See my question: "[Looking for CSS parser written in AS3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7531455/looking-for-css-parser-written-in-as3)" for a complete discussion but I found a CSS parser hidden inside the standard libraries.  Here is how you can use it:

```
public function extractFromStyleSheet(css:String):void {

    // Create a StyleSheet Object
    var styleSheet:StyleSheet = new StyleSheet();
    styleSheet.parseCSS(css);

    // Iterate through the selector objects
    var selectorNames:Array = styleSheet.styleNames;
    for(var i:int=0; i<selectorNames.length; i++){

        // Do something with each selector
        trace("Selector: "+selelectorNames[i];

        var properties:Object = styleSheet.getStyle(selectorNames[i]);
        for (var property:String in properties){

            // Do something with each property in the selector
            trace("\t"+property+" -> "+properties[property]+"\n");
        }
    }
}
```

You can then apply the styles using:

```
cssStyle = new CSSStyleDeclaration();
cssStyle.setStyle("color", "<valid color>);
FlexGlobals.topLevelApplication.styleManager.setStyleDeclaration("Button", cssStyle, true);
```

Comment: Why are you posting at an answered question which has an age of over 2 years?

Comment: @Rob I found this question by searching in Google and thought that the answer was incomplete.  My answer completes the question and will be helpful for people finding the question (like I did) from Google.