# In flex 4 Load css file from remote server

Tags: apache-flex, flex3, flex4

In Flex 4 i want to load css file from remote server at runtime it's possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the css file is compiled as a .swf file, yes:

```
StyleManager.getStyleManager(this.moduleFactory).loadStyleDeclarations("newStyle.swf");
```

Comment: Yes clement but i need without compiled(like .css) it is possible?

Comment: AFAIK, that's the only way unless you want to consider something a lot more convoluted like having a server call that spawns mxmlc to compile a CSS file on the fly.

Comment: hi clement please go through the link http://gilish.blogspot.com/2009/02/true-runtime-css-without-compiling-to.html

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/204924/how-do-you-dynamically-load-a-css-file-into-a-flex-application

Comment: hi celemet please go through this it's possible to load css form remote server.------ private function init():void { var urlLoader:URLLoader = new URLLoader(); urlLoader.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, urlcomplete); urlLoader.load(new URLRequest("cssUrl")); } private function urlcomplete(evt:Event):void { var css:String = evt.currentTarget.data.toString(); var styleSheet:StyleSheet = new StyleSheet(); styleSheet.parseCSS(css); var style:Object = null; style = styleSheet.getStyle(".labelstyle"); Label.textArea.setStyle("color", style.color); }